# Python Condition : String indices must be integers

Tags: python, string

[image]

I am trying to count the number of 'C's in each item in the list `bins`

The ideal output would be `c_counter = [1, 1, 1, 0]`

However when setting the condition `if item[i] == "C"`, I kept getting the error `string indices must be integers`

I tried converting it to int using `int(item[i])` but that didn't work too...

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `i` in your code is not an index, it’s a letter. When you loop over a string you get each letter. So you can just test `if i == ‘C’`, though in the case you might use a better variable name.

Comment: sorry very rookie mistake, thank you so much!!!

Comment: Also, please don’t post code as images. They are not accessible, are hard to search, and make people retype your code to help.

Comment: Try this -  ```counts = [item.count('C') for item in bins]```

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate over a string with a `for` loop, you in fact iterate over its characters, not indexes in the string. I.e.:

```py
for item in bins:
    for ch in item:
        if ch == 'C':
            c_counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you cause 'count' function :

```
bins=['ABCDE','ABCDE','GHCGA','B']
c_counter=[]
for i in bins:
  c_counter.append(i.count('C'))

c_counter
```

[image]